# How to test module using concerns and associations, via dummy ActiveRecord model in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the best way to test a module that uses associations, with a dummy active record class?

```
module Outputable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :output, as: outputable
  end

  delegate :print, to: :output
end
```

To use this module in a class, you'd make a new ActiveRecord model:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Outputable

  def initialize(output)
    self.output = output
  end
end

prog = Program.create(Output.create)
prog.print("hello world") # delegates to Output.print
```

I want to be able to use several types of classes, for example `Program`, `Log`, etc. But I have not defined these ActiveRecord models yet, I'd like to test with a dummy class in specs (similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868210/testing-a-concern-module-that-uses-activerecord)). I've tried the [Temping](https://github.com/jpignata/temping) gem, but maybe it is outdated, using Rails 4, Ruby 2.1.2 I get:

when trying to do `DummyProgram.create(output)` from:

```
Temping.create :dummy_program do
  include Outputable

  def initialize(output)
    self.output = output
  end
end

describe Outputable
  let(:output) { Output.create }
  let(:prog) { DummyProgram.create(output) }

  it "exposes Output methods" do
    expect(output).to receive(:print)
    prog.print("hello world!")
  end
end
```

I get a strange `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` method for the `DummyProgram.create(output)`. It works how ever if I do `DummyProgram.new(output)` but I need it to be saved to the temporary db.

Has anyone encountered a way around this, or an alternative to `temping` gem?

**Update**: For now, I'm going with manually creating and dropping a table:

```
describe Outputable do
  let(:output) { Output.create }
  let(:prog) { DummyProgram.create(output: output) }

  class DummyProgram < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Workflows::Outputable
  end

  before :all do
    m = ActiveRecord::Migration.new
    m.verbose = false
    m.create_table :dummy_program do |t|
      t.integer :workflow_id
      t.string :workflow_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  after :all do
    m = ActiveRecord::Migration.new
    m.verbose = false
    m.drop_table :dummy_program
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: Have a look at `acts_as_fu` gem.

Comment: Thanks, seems similar. I was hoping it would work but I think my module has too much namespacing/delegation inside of it, the gem's don't seem to pick that up. I get `uninitialized constant DummyProgram::Output` I think I might stick to manually creating and removing a db migration